why might pyspark code take so long even when only running lazy transformations?
I have a block of pyspark code, about 40 lines, with only lazy transformations. I've painstakingly removed every action method since I need to delay execution outside of this block of code. However, the block of code when benchmarked still takes 15 minutes! Is there a reason why that may be the case? Might execution trigger if a DAG got too large? Is there a way I can confirm if actions are being taken?
Unfortunately, I cannot share the code since it is for work. But, I will share every pyspark / DataFrame method I am calling in this block of code.

fillna
to_date
date_format
cast
join
withColumnRenamed
withColumn
select
lit
union
where
when
otherwise
orderBy
max (with window function)
lead
lag
row_number
isNull
groupBy
partitionBy
dropDuplicates


can you state how you are using withColumn/Renamed in psuedo code?  If you are using this in a loop / reduce / fold it's quite possibly responsible.

Also where is rename_cols coming from?

How/what do you benchmark? Also, some of these functions perform schema validation, so knowing the shape of your dataframe might be important.

maybe try adding .explain(extended=True, mode='cost') to the end of your code and looking at the physical plan

@chris yes, both withColumn and withColumnRenamed are being used in a loop. I tried refactoring that out but can pay closer attention to it. I'm trying to understand fundamentally why that would be an issue though? Again, I'm calling no action methods so I would not expect to pay the penalty for that yet in this section of code.

@mazaneicha which methods perform schema validation and will that happen before action is triggered?

.columns, .schema and a few others all force evaluation of the underlying data if you have things like mergeSchema enabled.

Most likely it is not spark issue, or you are missing some action method.
Unfortunately, it is hard to help here without looking actual code.
Maybe you can reproduce same without using your production code.
Also, try to comment parts of your method and execute code, this way you can easily find which part takes most time.
